# DataContract with inheritance change

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontract

I'm using DataContracts to serialize objects. Suppose I have serialized a data structured in this way:

```
[DataContract]
public class Dog : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public int age;

    [DataMember]
    public string name;

    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm changing my architecture and I would like to read the previously serialized data with this classes:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Dog))]
public class Animal : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name;

    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Dog : Animal
{
    [DataMember]
    public int age;
}
```

but I obtain name = null. I know that this depends on the order: the file was saved with age for first and then read starting from name, because it is on the base class.
Is there a way to handle this, maybe by changing the order?

Comment: Did the virtual suggestion work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

**The xml in the past would have been**

```
<dog>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <age>10</age>
</dog>
```

**Its now expecting**

```
<animal>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <dog>
        <age>10</age>
    </dog>
</animal>
```

The property is higher up in anything that's serialized on the new DataContract.
Changing inheritance heirarchy is a breaking change with the `IExtensibleDataObject` method.

> The use of inheritance together with data contracts is allowed,
>   provided that inheritance is not used as a versioning mechanism and
>   that certain rules are followed. If a type derives from a certain base
>   type, do not make it derive from a different base type in a future
>   version (unless it has the same data contract). There is one exception
>   to this: you can insert a type into the hierarchy between a data
>   contract type and its base type, but only if it does not contain data
>   members with the same names as other members in any possible versions
>   of the other types in the hierarchy. In general, using data members
>   with the same names at different levels of the same inheritance
>   hierarchy can lead to serious versioning problems and should be
>   avoided.

More at [Best Practices: Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832.aspx)

**Edit 1:**

You could perhaps try making Name virtual in Animal and overriding it in Dog?  Or some crazy method to force the serialized new version to have name under dog. i.e. something like,

```
[DataContract] 
[KnownType(typeof(Dog))] 
public class Animal : IExtensibleDataObject 
{
    public virtual string name; 

    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; } 
} 

[DataContract] 
public class Dog : Animal 
{ 
    [DataMember] 
    public override string name; 

    [DataMember] 
    public int age; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [WCF Contract Versioning discussed in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797193/175679).

Essentially you need to assign a [`Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.namespace.aspx) on your [`ServiceContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx) and keep both the new and old versions around if you want backwards compatibility as your contract evolves.

Comment: @silverninja I like it, referencing my own question ;)

Comment: Awesome...I didn't catch that! I read it yesterday and appreciated your recent posting. **WCF Versioning** is always something we've battled with, but we'd never made use of `Namespaces`.